# How to merge project in other project in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have two project same version in laravel 5.2. They both are of different purpose. The problem is how do I merge them in 1 project especially in laravel?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to merge them?

Comment: This is an ambiguous question as you do not provide any specific information about the situation. Regarding only your question, you should start by combining `routes` from both of them and perhaps restructuring your `controllers`, `models`, `middleware`, `views`, etc. in the same Laravel instance, but IMO, in separate subfolders, one for each project. You should be then very careful with namespaces in all files and classes. Nevertheless, if you provide more information, we will be able to help you better.

Comment: what if the two projects don't have the same version of Laravel. And what other informations you want me to add ??